# Filter SET by currentMember.MemberCaption

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, cube, olap-cube

I have a SET of members of some dimension, let's say [Dim].[Dim].[Dim]. Then I wrote a query that returns all the elements from this dimension for 2016 year of some measure, let's say there are 5 of such.

The next step that I want to make is to find first one member in this dimension with the same name (as CurrentMember in row) but for 2015 year. As result, I want to calculate some measure with regards to 2015-member, not 2016's.

So the problem is in scope - I can't GENERATE such set because CurrentMember's function scope will be equal to GENERATE's scope so I am unable to extract actual current member that is on row now and for which I want to find "same previous by name" members.

Am I able to do this with plain MDX or should I go with some workaround like finding such "same" elements in t-sql view and making child-parent relations in cube by hand? The second approach I think is very undesirable and ugly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just use .PrevMember on the Time (Year, I guess) dimension?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[SomePrevYearCalculation]
AS ([Time].[Year].CurrentMember.PrevMember,[Measures].[AMeasure])
SELECT
{[Measures].[AMeasure],[Measures].[Some2015Calculation]} ON 0,
[[Some complicated dimension stuff]] ON 1
FROM Cube
WHERE [Time].[Year].[2016]
```

Or are you dealing with a dimension that has multiple duplicate Names at leaf-level, so that you can't match the 2015 to 2016 figures by the actual dimension member?

Comment: Yes, I have no relations between the entities. Each entity in the table is unique id according to the year. In your query, I can't define what member of the dimension in previous year relates to the specific member in current row. I must find it by name.

Comment: That's clear thanks.  How about creating the dimension to be keyed on this Name that you're trying to match on?  If the id is specific to the year, it's no use as a dimension key for a dimension that will be useful over time.